# Where does Snort log the messages when using a pcap file?

Tags: snort

When you're using Snort for real-time monitoring the messages are logged to `/var/log/snort/alerts`.

However, when you load a pcap file, where do you see if any packet triggered a rule? Because they are not stored in that same directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind... the alerts are logged in the same directory. However the problem seems to be that even if I'm using the default configuration file, I need to use the `-c` parameter